# Where can I find the System.Linq.Dynamic dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am looking all over for this dll but can't find it anywhere? anyone know where to get it and can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get it from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) .  It's a zip file that contains the dynamic link source.  It's not a dll.

Originally posted on ScottGu's blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: ok thanks. what do I need to reference in my app to use it then?

Comment: Just add the Dynamic.cs file to your project.  It defines the namespace System.Linq.Dynamic.  In your code place: using System.Linq.Dynamic; at the top of the file.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone can explain why I can use OrderBy("someColumn") with this library but there is no definition for OrderByDescending("someColumn")? How would I order the elements in descending order when using Dynamic Library?

Comment: Is it possible that all I can do is OrderBy("someColumn").Reverse()? Seems like a hack to me...

Comment: @Marko I don't know if it is any less of a hack, but the way you do it is OrderBy("someColumn desc")

Comment: Thanks Geoff that is the solution I was looking for! I imagine that in my solution I traverse the IQueryable twice 1st time to order it initially and then 2nd time to reverse the order but I might be wrong on this. In any case thanks for the answer...

Comment: Gahhhh! Why doesn't OrderBy return IOrderedQueryable!?

Comment: Does Dynamic LINQ also support set a column on the fly something like this: 
.Foreach("x => x.@0 = x.@0 * @1", "SomeColumnName", 1.10)

Comment: Why dont use EF Dynamic SQL instead Dynamic LINQ ??
DbSet.SqlQuery()
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery()
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()

Answer (score 41):

Now it's available via [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic) gallery too.

Comment: Beware, the description on this NuGet package is misleading. It does state 'This is the Microsoft assembly', but the package owner is not Microsoft. It  really does not look like being officialy released by Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft never actually released dll, it was only published as code. But if you're suspicious, you can always decompile it.

Comment: @AndriyK I think that is a dangerous attitude. If the authors are malicious, they can later release an update with malware in the code. Even if the current version is clean, you are essentially choosing to trust the authors for as long as you use the library the lifetime of your project (and perhaps you even spread this trust to other projects!). In the end, there is a big difference between trusting Microsoft and some strangers on the internet that act in their name.

Comment: Same can be said about almost any nuget dependency you use. It's always matter of trust. 
On the other hand, if there are security issues with library that has roughly 400 downloads daily, you won't be only person to mention it, and it will be removed way before your updated code reaches production.

Answer (score 7):

Source file and .dll

[GitHub](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)