# Convert string to anonymous method

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>
                          {
                              new Person("Name1", "Surname1", 30),
                              new Person("Name2", "Surname2", 20),
                              new Person("Name3", "Surname3", 10)
                          };

        var filters = new List<Func<Person, bool>>
                          {
                              p => p.Age > 10,
                              p => p.Surname.Contains("2")
                          };

        var personsFiltered = new List<Person>(persons);
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            personsFiltered = personsFiltered.Where(filter).ToList();
        }

        foreach (var person in personsFiltered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Surname { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, string surname, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Age = age;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name:{0}, Surname:{1}, Age:{2}", Name, Surname, Age);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass filters as string parameters, so that the user could create custom filters? For example, the `filters` list in my example would initially be empty and the user would provide strings "p => p.Age > 10" and "p => p.Surname.Contains(\"2")"?

Comment: Maybe deserialize the string version back into an object before you use them in code? EDIT: That string would not work and would need to be in the serialized format.

Comment: You can use Dynamic Linq Extensions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991108/where-can-i-find-the-system-linq-dynamic-dll

Comment: And when your user gives you `p => (p.Age / 0) == 2` ? (half-joking...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to allow the user to write code for your application : A scripting engine and dynamic compilation.

**LUA**

You could integrate a scripting engine like Lua (I found that very easy) : /technical/game-programming/using-lua-with-c-r2275">http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources//technical/game-programming/using-lua-with-c-r2275

You need to create a Lua environment, set the variables to be used by the user's script, then read the variables from that environment. I built a partly scripted printing template engine using this method and it worked perfectly. LuaInterface for C# is very intuitive and simple.

**DYNAMIC COMPILATION**

Another option is to implement dynamic compilation (a little more trouble, but more powerful) : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DynamicCompileAndRun.aspx

You need to create a framework class and concatenate a string to include the user's script inside a class that implements a certain interface. Something like :

```
class ClientScript : IScriptFramework {
    public override String Method(Object object) {
        return %CLIENT_CODE%;
    }
}
```

Assuming IScriptFramework declares Method, you can store an isntance of this class into a IScriptFramework and call Method without any reflection. Just store this code in a resource, generate the final source code by replacing %CLIENT_CODE% with the actual code (like object.ToString()) and compiling that in memory as described in the post I linked.

I used dynamic compilation for a testing framework and it works pretty well, although the syntax is more strict than a script engine like Lua.

EDIT : Viacheslav Smityukh is right, there is a framework that does the hard job of dynamically compiling LINQ queries for you. I read about it a while back, but I didn't think about before I saw his comment. It may be the easiest way to go for you : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx