# Converting Where from LINQ clause to dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I want to go from

```
        var selectData = (from i in data
                          where i.Name == "Bob1"
                          select i);
```

To

```
        var selectData = (from i in data
                          select i).Where("Name==Bob1");
```

I've tried various approaches (`AsQueryable`, `Where<SomeData>`), but can't get the second form to compile.

I do not have a good grasp on C#'s generic extension methods.  The `<Tsource>` doesn't make sense to me so that could be the problem.  Also, I do not understand why I can type `.Where()` when intellisense only displays `.Where<>` (a generic).  I expect to see a second `Where` without the generic symbol...alas I do not.

Class

```
public class SomeData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**
There appears to be some confusion as to how Where() can be used that may well be my fault.  Please see a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries) question.  Based off this answer, the property name in the where clause is perfectly legal.  I need the property to remain a string.  If that means dynamic LINQ is required, then so be it...that's what I need.

Comment: This seems similar to another post.  Maybe this will help

[LINQ - dynamic WHERE clause?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause

Comment: You need to dynamically query your property names? Can you confirm this?

Comment: I still don't understand. If you're looking for how to do dynamic Linq, is the answer you already cited on the [other question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries) not already the answer to this question too?

Comment: @Paul Ruane - I am trying to get the other answer to work.  I assumed Dynamic LINQ was just a part of .NET OOB functionality. And that I was doing something syntactically incorrect. Obviously that is not the case.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I've had a quick read around. Appears it may be a [separate download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991108/where-can-i-find-the-system-linq-dynamic-dll#3991141).

Comment: @PaulRuane yes, it's a separate download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all your help I have managed to get the conversion to function.

1. Install Dynamic LINQ (I used NUGET.  Search online for System.Linq.Dynamic)
2. Add `using System.Linq.Dynamic`
3. Query should be of the form

   ```
       var selectData = (from i in data
                         select i).AsQueryable().Where("Name = @0","Bob1");//@0 is called an identifier.  "Name = Bob1" straight up fails.
   ```
4. Install ScottGU's [C# sample library](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1332355934&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US)...it helps. ([VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb964686.aspx)) ([Original Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

```
var selectData = (from i in data
                  select i).Where(datum => datum.Name == "Bob1");
```

The `Where` method takes a delegate, not a string, so you need to pass in a delegate or lambda.

Edit: based upon your comment to one of the other answers, you will need to use Reflection to make the property value lookup dynamic.

Edit: looks like you need to [download the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991108/where-can-i-find-the-system-linq-dynamic-dll#3991141) for the Dynamic Linq library separately.

Comment: If that is the case, please explain this other related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: That uses dynamic Linq. You could certainly explore that but that is not what you asked in your question.

Comment: So am I to assume dynamic LINQ is an add-on that I need to download and reference?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I have no idea, I've never used it. I'm reading the link posted in the accepted answer in your other question as we speak.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I misunderstood the question initially; the solution to the problem is to download Dynamic Linq and reference it.  I'll leave my answer below it addresses the side questions you asked about generic extension methods.

---

```
var selectData = (from i in data 
    select i).Where(d => d.Name=="Bob1");
```

But why not this:

```
var selectData = data.Where(d => d.Name=="Bob1");
```

Regarding the "non-generic" version of where, there is no such thing.  In the calls above, the type parameter of the generic method is implicit; it has been inferred by the compiler, which compiles the call exactly as it would compile this:

```
var selectData = data.Where<SomeData>(d => d.Name=="Bob1");
```

Perhaps a sketch implementation of the `Where` method will help reduce your confusion about the `TSource` parameter:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
        if (predicate(item))
            yield return item;
}
```

`TSource` is the element type of the sequence you are querying.  It's also the element type of the result sequence.

The compiler needs to know the type for at least two reasons:

First, we need to call a function on each element to determine whether to include it in the result sequence.  The compiler has to know that the referent of the `predicate` parameter can safely accept a parameter of type TSource.

The second reason is somewhat trivial in this case; `item` has to be assignment compatible with `TSource` because it is used in a `yield return` statement.  Of course it is compatible, because it is of the same type.

Comment: I can't do that.  I need the property as a string.

Comment: What do you mean "need the property as a string"?  The property *is* a string.  Do you mean you want to select the value of the property as a string?  If so, the value will be "Bob1".  If you describe the desired value of `selectData` perhaps it will help clarify.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey do you mean that you want to specify the property being queried at run-time, by passing its name to the method as a string?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey ok!  In that case, using extension method syntax won't help.  Query comprehension syntax is semantically equivalent to extension method syntax; the compiler translates the query into extension methods anyway.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I added some material about generics that will, I hope, help clear up some of the confusion you mentioned about the `TSource` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Example

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Source code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class PredicateBuilder
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code using an Expression tree to do what you want.  This will only work for Property == "..." queries against that particular type.  You can of course modify this and make it as generic as you need.

```
    public void Test()
    {
        List<SomeData> data = new List<SomeData>();
        data.Add(new SomeData("Mark", "Ledgewood Drive"));
        data.Add(new SomeData("Tim", "Sumpter Drive"));
        data.Add(new SomeData("Sean", "Leroy Drive"));
        data.Add(new SomeData("Bob", "Wilmington Road"));
        data.Add(new SomeData("Sean", "Sunset Blvd"));

        List<SomeData> result = data.Where(BuildExpression("Name", "Mark")).ToList();
        List<SomeData> result2 = data.Where(BuildExpression("Address", "Wilmington Road")).ToList();
    }

    private Func<SomeData, bool> BuildExpression(string propertyName, string value)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeData), "someData");
        Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, propertyName);
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(value);
        BinaryExpression binary = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        Expression<Func<SomeData, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeData, bool>>(binary, pe);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
```