# Invoking Regex.IsMatch() inside a dynamic linq query

Tags: c#, regex, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to invoke the `Regex.IsMatch()` and evaluate the returned result inside a dynamic linq query. This is what I tried:

```
public static LambdaExpression Parse(SearchQuery query)
{
    string compilableExpression = "Regex.IsMatch(Category.ToLower(), \"\\bSomeCat\\b\", RegexOptions.Compiled) == true";

    ParameterExpression parameter1 = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventListItem));
    ParameterExpression parameter2 = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(Regex));

    return System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter1, parameter2 }, null, compilableExpression);
}
```

In this case `Category` is a property in the `EventListItem`. This exception is thrown upon calling `ParseLambda()`:

`Unknown identifier 'Regex'`.

Is there a way to invoke the method? I came across `Expression.Call()` method, but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't used `System.Linq.Dynamic` a lot, but here is a way to make your example work:

1 - You really only have one input object, your `EventListItem`, so remove parameter2 (Regex):

```
string compilableExpression = "Regex.IsMatch(Category.ToLower(), \"\\bSomeCat\\b\", RegexOptions.Compiled) == true";
ParameterExpression parameter1 = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventListItem));
return System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter1 }, null, compilableExpression);
```

2 - `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda()` is made to read properties and methods from the *input object*. Using methods on other classes (here: `Regex.IsMatch()` is limited to a small set of predefined classes, and by default `Regex` isn't one of them.

Therefore, we somehow need to make the parser realize that "Regex" is a class and not a property on EventListItem. Assuming you have included the [DynamicLinq.cs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991108/where-can-i-find-the-system-linq-dynamic-dll#answer-10139936) in your project, this can be done by adding Regex (and RegexOptions) to the internal `ExpressionParser.predefinedTypes` array:

```
static readonly Type[] predefinedTypes = {
    typeof(Object),
    typeof(Boolean),
    ...

    typeof(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex), 
    typeof(System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions),
};
```

**EDIT: Complex parameter values**
If we need to include more complex parameters in our method calls, e.g. a combined RegexOptions enum; `RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, ParseLambda also accepts a list of `values`.

We prepare the combined enum beforehand, and submit it in that values list. In `compilableExpression` we include placeholders for the values we submit, indexed in the same order we submit them (here we only have one value - index 0)

```
var options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
string compilableExpression = "Regex.IsMatch(Category.ToLower(), \"\\bSomeCat\\b\", @0) == true";
ParameterExpression parameter1 = SLE.Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventListItem));
return SLD.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter1 },
                                         null,
                                         compilableExpression,
                                         options);
```

*Bonus: Because the RegexOptions class/enum is no longer directly referenced in compilableExpression, we also no longer need to include RegexOptions in ExpressionParser.predefinedTypes.*

Comment: If I could upvote this 5 times I would! I figured out a workaround but this makes my life a lot easier. Just one more thing, when passing in the `RegexOptions`, can I pass in more than one? I tried `RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` but it says `'(' or ',' expected`. Any idea?

Comment: @programmer93 - The DynamicExpression class isn't a full-blown C# parser, so it probably doesn't understand that syntax. I have updated my answer with a workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna have so much fun with this :)

Comment: Has anybody run into this exception when implementing this solution?  After I develop the LambdaExpression, I feed into .Where() and get the following:  "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @Ken - That exception is not related to dynamic linq, but rather to the fact that Linq2Entities doesn't know how to translate the `Regex.IsMatch()` method into SQL. See this post and the accepted answer: [linq to entities doesn't recognize a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845993/linq-to-entities-doesnt-recognize-a-method)