# Pass an Enum as parameter in DynamicExpression

Tags: c#, dynamic, expression

I am using `ParseLambda` from `System.Linq.DynamicExpression` namespace. More info can be found on [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).

The following code throws `Unknown identifier 'TeamType'` exception

```
public bool CheckCondition()
{
    try
    {
        var condition = "CurrentUser.CurrentTeamType == TeamType.Admin";
        var currentUserParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(UserInfo), "CurrentUser");
        var dynamicExpression = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { currentUserParameter}, null, condition);
        var result = dynamicExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(CurrentUserInfo);
        return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      // do some stuff then throw it again
      throw ex;
    }
}

public enum TeamType
{
    Admin = 1,
    AnotherType = 2
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public short UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public TeamType CurrentTeamType { get; set; }
}
```

`CurrentUserInfo` is just an instance of `UserInfo`;

My question is what can I do so `TeamType` will be recognized, or how can I pass the enum as parameter.

Additional exceptions:

If I change `condition` to `Convert.ToInt32(CurrentUser.CurrentTeamType) == 1`, I get the following exception
`Expression of type 'Namespace.TeamType' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)'`

If I change `condition` to `(int)CurrentUser.CurrentTeamType == 1`, I get the following exception `Unknown identifier 'int'`

If I add namespace too like `var condition = "CurrentUser.CurrentTeamType == App.BE.TeamType.Admin";`, I get `Unknown identifier 'App'`. Please note that I have a reference to `App.BE` namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full namespace to TeamType. Since you are using it in a string, it probably just needs you to be more specific.

UPDATE:

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681838/1152054) will help you. You need to set up predefined types ahead of time.

Comment: I've tried that in the first. I will update my question

Comment: A reference in the class is meaningless, because you are sending in a string. Use the full namespace as if there are no 'using' statements.

Comment: Updated my question. I've done that but only posted `BE` instead `App.BE`

Comment: You need to be super clear here, since we can't see all your code. So if you put `App.BE` in, the error still says `BE` is the problem? Is `App.BE` added as a reference in your project? If you typed `App.BE` in the above method, does it resolve? If not, you are missing a needed project reference.

Comment: As i said in question, references are ok. If i type App.BE i see intelisense for it.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to that question

Answer (score 0):

There is much easier solution - just use text representation of enum value, i.e. this will work:

```
var condition = "CurrentUser.CurrentTeamType == \"Admin\"";
```