# System.Linq.Dynamic to invoke action

Tags: c#, linq

I am using `System.Linq.Dynamic` to invoke actions dynamically , Attached below my code.

```
 void InvokeAction(object gv, string lambda) {
 var e = myalias.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(gv.GetType(), null, lambda);
 e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(gv);
}

var gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = (new int[] {
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5
}).Select(p => new {
 f1 = "f1", f2 = "f2", f3 = "f3"
});
gv.DataBind();
InvokeAction(gv, "HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = \"a\"");
// Runs fine , but does not update the value
InvokeAction(gv, "HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White");
// Gives exception No property or field 'System' exists in type 'GridView'
```

First call to InvokeAction runs fine , but does not update the value .
Second call to InvokeAction throws exception

> No property or field 'System' exists in type 'GridView'

Comment: What does not work? What happens?

Comment: I have updated the details with what does not work and exception that I get

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681838/622391) of use - it talks about how to _"make the parser realize that [System.Drawing.Color] is an [enum] and not a property on [GridView]"_

Comment: Why are you using Linq.Dynamic?