# Regex.IsMatch() in dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

how to invoke `Regex.IsMatch()` in `IQueryable`?
i found the same question but it doesnt work
[Invoking Regex.IsMatch() inside a dynamic linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679722/invoking-regex-ismatch-inside-a-dynamic-linq-query)

first i have

```
IQueryable Database = data.Verses.Select($"new {{ ID, {TextSearchType.ToString()} }}");
```

ive tried

```
var searchResult = Database.Where(Parse());

public static LambdaExpression Parse()
{
    ParsingConfig.Default.CustomTypeProvider = new MyCustomTypeProvider();
    var options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
    string compilableExpression = $"Regex.IsMatch({TextSearchType.ToString()}, \"(^| ){Keyword}($| )\", @0) == true";
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Verses));
    var DynamicExpression = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter },
                                             null,
                                             compilableExpression,
                                             options);
    return DynamicExpression;
}
public class MyCustomTypeProvider : DefaultDynamicLinqCustomTypeProvider
{
    public override HashSet<Type> GetCustomTypes()
    {
        return new HashSet<Type>
                {
                    typeof(Object),
                    typeof(Boolean),
                    typeof(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex),
                    typeof(System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions),
                };
    }
}
```

`TextSearchType` is property name in Verses class.
im getting this error

> No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is
> compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
> arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

here is the linq code the im trying to convert to linq dynamic

```
var rx = new Regex("(^| )" + keyword + "($| )", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var searchResult = Database.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => rx.IsMatch(x.AyahText)).ToList();
```

Comment: What type of database are you querying?

Comment: sql server with ef6 code first .

Comment: I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: i came up with solution, i just loop thru Database then if (rx.IsMatch(verse)) SearchResultObj.Add(ayah); silly me, but thanks any way :)

Comment: can you provide your findings as a proper answer?!

Comment: Use `StartsWith`/`EndsWIth`/`Contains` instead of a regex in your example e.g. (`(x.AyahText == keyword || x.AyahText.StartsWith(keyword+" ") || x.AyahText.EndsWith(" "+keyword) || x.AyahText.Contains(" "+keyword+" ")`).

Answer (score 2):

You can not call `IsMatch` or any other Non-SQL supported functions (see the full list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)) in LINQ to Entities.

In order to do what you want, you to have two possible options (maybe more, but I know two at this moment):

1. Get the items by raw filtering (without using `IsMatch`), converting the result to `List`, by calling `.ToList()` at the end of your query. And then you can filter the collection by `Regex.IsMatch`.
   *To be honest, this is not a greater solution, and I wouldn't say I like it.*
2. Create a stored procedure and call it from the c# (official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/creating-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions-with-managed-code-cs)).