# Entity framework query without lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lambda

So I'm writing a 'semi-generic' class that fits the same pattern over and over again with the signature

```
public class BaseSupportRepo<TEntity, TDto> where TEntity : class where TDto : class
```

All of the repos that use this class have one property which is `Name`

What I want to do is write a function that will return a .Single() if a name matches some input (however name is not a primary key).

Now if this was a non generic function it'd be easy since

```
.Single(g => g.Name == name)
```

However because this is a generic function the .Name property cannot be used since TEntity may not have any property Name.

Is there any function in EF that can allow something akin to  :-

```
.Single(string key, string value)
```

This would allow me to get around this requirement.

Comment: Why not just create a INamedEntity { string Name } and where TEntity : INamedEntity and make all your entities implement TEntity

Comment: Can you use [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create interface:

```
public interface IEntityWithName
{
    string Name { get; set;}
}
```

And change Your repo to:

```
public class BaseSupportRepo<TEntity, TDto> where TEntity : class, IEntityWithName 
                                            where TDto : class
```

If You have a generated code using edmx file you can change your T4 template that generates Your classes to implement `IEntityWithName` or create partial classes like this:

```
public partial class SomeEntity : IEntityWithName
{
}
```

You can then write a query that can use `Name`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get at the Entity classes since they are generated using a tool :|

Comment: If entities are partial classes you can put the interface in a partial class on your own file

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this story: [Where can I find the System.Linq.Dynamic dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991108/where-can-i-find-the-system-linq-dynamic-dll). Dynamic.cs was written by someone at Microsoft I believe and it allows you to write Linq queries using strings rather than lambdas. It has come in handy for me in the project I'm currently working on.